# Heroku Rails app push failed at Compiling Ruby/Rails - stack issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I pushed code to Heroku last night and it worked, but today it is not. It is failing just after 'Compiling Ruby/Rails' with this line

```
remote:  !     Debug InformationCommand: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-18/ruby-2.1.2.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !
remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

I have updated my ruby to 2.3.7 but have the same problem.

I am still on cedar-14 stack, so perhaps the reference to heroku-18 is an issue but I don't know where to find or change this.

Elsewhere I found a reference to parsing issues with config variables but I have no open brackets or double quotes there.

Is it really time to finally update the stack? Can I not do some other time sensitive updates first before potentially breaking everything....?

Appreciate any advice. I don't really understand the stack.

Comment: did you specified the ruby version on your gemfile?

Comment: Check your buildpack situation. It's possible that you could switch them out without upgrading. You should only need the base heroku/ruby buildpack.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! Turns out heroku upgraded our stack to heroku-18 but for some reason the app info is still saying cedar-14. I will report back with details after I get it working

Comment: `heroku stack:set cedar-14` fixes everything